# OpenGL: Rotate, Scale, and Translate a Triangle

Tags: c++, function, opengl, matrix

Given this matrix which I derived from multiplying a rotate and scale matrix by a translate matrix, I'm attempting to write two functions, `x1` and `y1`, to allow me to plug in values that will scale a triangle twice, rotate it `90` degrees, and translate it to `(7,8)`.

```
|(Sx)(cos a)   (Sy)(sin a)   0|
|(Sx)(-sin a)  (Sy)(cos a)   0|
|DeltaX        DeltaY        1|

Sx = scale in x
Sy = scale in y
DeltaX = translation in x
DeltaY = translation in y
a = alpha
```

I'm just not sure where to begin on this one, so any and all help is much appreciated. Oh, and my professor mentioned that this will be one of the only times we will have to do this so I'm guessing *OpenGL* has some shortcuts for this... that I'm sadly not allowed to use. Thanks for your time!

Comment: What are the two functions supposed to do and what code have you done so far?

Comment: There doesn't have to be any code, just the two functions, and all he told us was to find function of x1 = f(x,y, sin a, cos a, DeltaX, DeltaY, Sx, Sy) and y1 = g(x,y, sin a, cos a, DeltaX, DeltaY, Sx, Sy).

Comment: If you don't have a programming question then you are on the wrong site.